# Angular 2.0.0 final - Custom Pipe filtering with multiple from field conditions

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-pipe

I am trying to filter foods with multiple from field conditions *(input & drop-down)*. I can filter them separately, but I can't figure out how to **make them work together**.

I've created two separate Custom Pipes *(one for the input filter and one for the drop-down filter)* to make thing more modular.

Here is the logic behind the Input Pipe:

```
// Input Filter
transform(value: IProduct[], filter: string): IProduct[] {
    filter = filter ? filter.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
    return filter ? value.filter((product: IProduct) =>
        product.prodName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1) : value;
}
```

the logic behind the Dropdown Pipe:

```
// Dropdown Filter
transform(value: IProduct[], filter: string): IProduct[] {
    return filter ? value.filter((product: IProduct) =>
        product.prodCategory.indexOf(filter) !== -1) : value;
}
```

This is the custom pipe in the template view:

```
<tr *ngFor='let _product of _products | DropdownProductFilter: ddlistFilter.name ||  InputProductFilter: listFilter'
```

Here is a the example 
http://plnkr.co/qwsk86hHLbI26w3HVMdV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your template, change your `||` to `|` will do the trick:

```
<tr *ngFor='let _product of _products | DropdownProductFilter: ddlistFilter.name |  InputProductFilter: listFilter'>
```